# Is there a list of Microsoft Azure Cloud Services by release date / GA?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-notificationhub, azure-hub

In part to help explain or understand "what components build on which others" in Azure, or show others the time and evolution of thinking as products were released (console vs portal for example), is there a list of when products were released to the public?

I checked Wikipedia for this and found no historical data, (hoping it would be in table form by date/status/release/LTS)

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest would be the RSS feed from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/

It includes updates about features going to Preview and General Availability.

---

You could also try with the Wayback Machine on the [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/) page.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180604154430/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/) is a version from 2018. The page changed into a search type page so you'll need to try see if archive.org has versions of the region specific pages.

[Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=australia-central,australia-central-2,australia-east,australia-southeast&products=all) gives you a NOW-only view with the following key:

- Generally Available
- In Preview
- In Preview (hover to view expected timeframe)
- Future availability (hover to view expected timeframe)